# jQuery not detecting clicks on dynamically inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have the following modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="mt" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="mb" class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div id="mf" class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a button in a table, which kicks off a jquery ajax call and pulls in the title, body, and footer of the modal. You can see that script below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a.btn').click(function(){
    var org_id = $(this).attr('org_id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/groups/' + org_id + '/leave',
        success: function(data){       
            var data = $('<div>').html(data);
            var msg1 = data.find('#msg1');
            var msg2 = data.find('#msg2');
            var msg3 = data.find('#msg3');
            $('#mf').html(msg3);
            $('#mt').html(msg2);
            $('#mb').html(msg1);
        }
    });
});

$('#killgroup').click(function(){
    alert('made it');
    });
});
</script>
```

Once the modal is fully populated with data, the footer section looks like this:

```
<div id="mf" class="modal-footer"><div id="msg3"><a id="killgroup" class="btn btn-danger">I'm Positive. Kill Group Forever.</a><a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success">Wait! Let me re-think this.</a></div></div>
```

The problem that i'm having is that when I click the button with the id, "killgroup", it does nothing. If you look above at my jquery code, the second section tries to react to that button click:

```
$('#killgroup').click(function(){
alert('made it');
});
```

});

I cannot get that to work. It seems as though there might be a chicken before the egg issue going on here but I am very new to jquery / javascript so I am not sure. Basically, I want to be able to click that dynamically created button and kick off another jquery script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code:

```
$('#killgroup').click(function(){ ... });
```

...says to find an element with id `'killgroup'` which exists *at the moment that code runs* and then assign a click handler to that element.

In your case of course the element doesn't exist yet. The two usual ways to make it work are to either move the `.click()` call to just after the code that creates the element (in your Ajax callback) or to use a delegated click handler bound to a parent element that does exist at the time (or bound to the `document` if there is no parent element):

```
$('.modal-content').on('click', '#killgroup', function() {
   alert('made it');
});
```

That variation of the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will bind the handler to the element(s) in the jQuery object - in this case I've used `'.modal-content'` because you know that exists at the start - and then when a click occurs jQuery automatically tests whether the click originated in a child of that element that matches the selector in the second argument, `'#killgroup'`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the .on() function for dynamically loaded elements...

The problem is you're assigning a click handler to a non existant element.

This will fix your issue.....

```
$(document).on('click','#killgroup',function(){
   alert('made it');
 });
```

It used to be the .live() function, but that was deprecated.  .on() should do the trick